# How to enable the Spotlight shortcut in OS X while allowing japanese characters input?

Tags: macos, shortcuts, spotlight

According to [this page](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/cdb_sptfky.html) the keyboard shortcut to open the Spotlight menu in OS X is <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

However, I am using a japanese macbook pro. When I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> the language input mode changes (switching between latin characters, japanese hiragana, japanese katakana).

How can I set the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to open the Spotlight menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the keyboard shortcut that actually activates the Spotlight search bar on my computer.
It was CTRL+Spacebar.

Answer (score 2):

In `System Preferences > Keyboard`, select `Keyboard and Text Input` on the left and un-check `Select previous input source` on the right.

You may also want to uncheck the `Select next source in Input menu` item to enable <kbd>⌘⌥ Space</kbd> (Command-Option-Space) as the Spotlight-in-Finder shortcut.

Comment: Sorry CajunLuke, but unchecking this settings does not focus the Spotlight search menu. Instead, at best nothing happens, and from Finder a window opens with the message "No Items Selected".

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences → Input Sources → Keyboard → Spotlight → Check the spotlight menu keyboard shortcut → Double click the existing shortcut (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>) → Change it to the shortcut key you prefer

For language switch, I use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
For spotlight, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

[Source](http://sanziro.com/2011/04/how-to-setup-keyboard-shortcuts-to-easily-switch-between-language-input-methods-in-mac-os-x.html)